# populate DataGridView from database and TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Basically I want to add another column from a `TextBox` along with values I have queried from the database. I want my datagridview to show something like

```
          |itemcode|Category|itemDescription|unitcost|quantity|
```

where `itemcode, Category, itemDescription, unitcost` is from database and `quantity` is from a text box input.

```
private void btnAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.OpenConnection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = con.connection.CreateCommand();
    string search = txtSearchProduct.Text;
    string quantity = txtQuantity.Text;
    string query = "SELECT itemcode, Category, itemDescription, unitcost FROM tblprowareproducts WHERE itemDescription LIKE ?search";
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?search", "%" + search + "%");
    using (MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        mda.Fill(dt);

        dgvCart.DataSource = dt;

    }
}
```

Is there a way to add another column after `unitcost`  named `quantity` and the value of it comes from a `TextBox`?

Comment: And what's the problem? What's the expected result? What's the result which you received?

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different solutions for the problem, for example you can add the column to `DataTable` this way:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
mda.Fill(dt);

var quantity = dt.Columns.Add("quantity", typeof(int));
quantity.DefaultValue = int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text);
dt.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(r =>
{
    r[quantity] = quantity.DefaultValue;
});

dgvCart.DataSource = dt;
```

**Note 1**: You may want to use `TryParse` to get the integer value from text.

**Note 2**: Default value of column applies to the column when adding the row. So to apply it to existing rows, you need to use a loop like what I did. For new rows that you add after that, it will be applied automatically.